# firestore filter range date

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Why when I do this filter it returns all records from my database?
What I need is that it returns only records within the range of the two dates.

```
async function toFind() {
console.log("start", dateRangePicker.start);
console.log("end", dateRangePicker.end);
const importacao = db.collection("importacao");
 await importacao
  .orderBy('data')
  .where("data", '>=', dateRangePicker.start)
  .where("data", '<=', dateRangePicker.end)
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      toast.error('No matching documents.');
      return;
    }
```

{
//database
comentario: "teste",
custo:"3,000",
data:"18/08/2021",
dolar:"5.56"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be storing your dates as string values with the format "dd/MM/yyyy". That is not a great format for storing dates, as strings are ordered [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) and in that order "18/08/2021" is **before** "19/09/2020".

If you want to store dates, do so in an [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format like "2021-08-18". In that format the lexicographical order is the same as the chronological order, so you get the result you want.

Comment: Friend, I would never have imagined this, thank you very much, you made a Brazilian's day happier!!